# Dictionary Item not populating correctly

Tags: vba, dictionary

I am out of wits on this one. I have a list like below that is available on the fly. I want to be able to create an array or a collection so that I could use it further in a loop.

```
Xob::SISBTXTRPR-5298 
Xob::SISBTXTRPR-5326 
Xob::SISBTXTRPR-5327 
Xob::SISBTXTRPR-5328
Yob::SISBTXTRPR-3999
Yob::SISBTXTRPR-4000
```

I have tried to create a dictionary item like below but the output is not what I am expecting

```
While i <= iPuntedIssuesCount 
    If sRemovedStoriesForTaskTracker.Exists(Trim(JSONObj("contents")("puntedIssues")(i)("assigneeName"))) Then
        sRemovedStoriesForTaskTracker(Trim(JSONObj("contents")("puntedIssues")(i)("assigneeName"))) = sRemovedStoriesForTaskTracker(Trim(JSONObj("contents")("puntedIssues")(i)("assigneeName"))) & " + " & JSONObj("contents")("puntedIssues")(i)("key") 
    Else
        sRemovedStoriesForTaskTracker.Add key:=Trim(JSONObj("contents")("puntedIssues")(i)("assigneeName")), Item:=JSONObj("contents")("puntedIssues")(i)("key")
    End If
    i = i + 1
Wend
```

sRemovedStoriesForTaskTracker is the dictionary item.
The output in the dictionary items that I am getting is like so:

```
Xob::SISBTXTRPR-5298 + SISBTXTRPR-5326 + SISBTXTRPR-5327 + SISBTXTRPR-5328.
```

I want the dictionary to populate like this

```
Xob::SISBTXTRPR-5298 
Xob::SISBTXTRPR-5326 
Xob::SISBTXTRPR-5327 
Xob::SISBTXTRPR-5328
```

Comment: That is because your key is always `Xob:` and the items are `SISBTXTRPR` and  the negative numbers. Since the key already exists, it will do the first statement on your if. A sidenote, would be good for reading, assigning the key and item to `String`variables and use them instead the whole `JSON` object.

Answer (score 0):

You don't show your source JSON, or how you're outputting the dictionary values, and your posted code doesn't seem to match what you say you want to do.

In any case, your code as-posted would benefit hugely from the use of a few variables as noted by @Damian.  It's so dense it's difficult to follow.

```
While i <= iPuntedIssuesCount

    Set d = JSONObj("contents")("puntedIssues")(i)
    k = Trim(d("assigneeName"))
    v = d("key")

    If dictRemoved.Exists(k) Then
        dictRemoved(k) = dictRemoved(k) & " + " & v 
    Else
        dictRemoved.Add k, v
    End If
    i = i + 1

Wend
```